# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

i am trying to send email from an **application email** (exchange server) and appear for the user as it was sent from **another email** using **javamail**, i am using the following code:

```
public void sendEmail(String from, String to, String subject, String emailBody) throws Exception {

        try {

            emailHostSMTPs = MessageProvider.getConfig("email.host.smtps");
            emailHostSMTP = MessageProvider.getConfig("email.host.smtp");
            emailProtocol = MessageProvider.getConfig("email.protocol");
            senderEmail = MessageProvider.getConfig("email.sender");
            senderPassword = MessageProvider.getConfig("email.password");
            senderUser = MessageProvider.getConfig("email.sender.user");
            MimeMessage msg = null;

            // BodyPart imgPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            MimeBodyPart mbp1 = null, mbp2 = null;
            MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

            String html = "";

            Properties props = System.getProperties();

            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", emailProtocol);
            props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.checkserveridentity", "false");
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", emailHostSMTP);
            props.put("mail." + emailProtocol + ".auth", "true");

            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();

            MailSSLSocketFactory sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
            sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory", sf);

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
            session.setDebug(true);

            mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();

            html = "<html><body> " + emailBody + " </body></html>";
            mbp1.setContent(html, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);

            msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
            msg.setContent(mp);

            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            Transport transport = session.getTransport(emailProtocol);

            transport.connect(senderEmail, senderPassword);
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

        @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            String username = senderUser;

            String password = senderPassword;
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    }
```

the authentication is made with **senderEmail** but i want the email to appear as it was sent from the **from** user, but i am getting the following exception:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
    at com.dataserve.ecm.service.EmailService.sendEmail(EmailService.java:76)
    at com.dataserve.ecm.beans.GenericSearch.sendDocumentByEmail(GenericSearch.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:328)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:341)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.PostprocessorFilter.doFilter(PostprocessorFilter.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ContainerBasedFilter.doFilter(ContainerBasedFilter.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.PreprocessorFilter.doFilter(PreprocessorFilter.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.SecurityPluginFilter.doFilter(SecurityPluginFilter.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.dataserve.ecm.ui.CompitabilityFilter.doFilter(CompitabilityFilter.java:41)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:522)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:311)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
```

please advise how to fix this exception.

Comment: Bill Shannon is right, but the utterly answer is @Barani r 's one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your server isn't going to let you do this.  If it did, you could send spam as anyone.  If this is your private server, you might be able to reconfigure it to allow this.

Answer (score 7):

In msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from)); 
"from" should be a valid email setup in the SMTP server.  You may need to contact your SMTP server admin and get the User ID setup for you.